# React Tinymce Quickbar add font-size options as input field

Tags: reactjs, tinymce

I am using `React TinyMCE` for text editor this is my code.

```
<Editor
  key={id}
  initialValue={value}
  inline={true}
  init={{
    plugins: [ 'quickbars', 'autoresize', 'code', 'paste', 'link' ],
    menubar: false,
    toolbar: false,
    quickbars_insert_toolbar: false,
    quickbars_selection_toolbar: selection_toolbar,
    browser_spellcheck : true,
    autoresize_bottom_margin: 50,
    autoresize_overflow_padding: 50,
    min_height: 100,
    valid_elements: "*[*]",
    paste_as_text: true,
    font_formats: fonts(),
    content_css: [
      customfontStyle
    ],
    setup: (editor) => {
      editorRef.current = editor;

      editor.on('drop', e => {
        console.log(e);
        e.preventDefault();
      });

    }
  }}
  onEditorChange={onChange}
/>
);
```

[image]

Here the `font-size` is a `drop-down` and I am aware I can add/remove font sizes from the list. but I want the `font-size` option to be an input field to enter `font-size`. Would that be possible. Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 1):

`TinyMCE` has a [`setup`](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/integration-and-setup/#setup) property which allows you to specify a callback that will be executed before the `TinyMCE` editor instance is rendered:

```
 setup: function (editor) {
    editor.on('click', function () {
      console.log('Editor was clicked');
    });
```

`editor` which you give in the setup function, allows you to add predefined component to toolbar. Unfortunately it doesn't support `input` or something like that, But you can add this [components](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/ui-components/) to toolbar. One of them is [`button`](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/ui-components/typesoftoolbarbuttons/#basicbutton). So it can be added to toolbar like this:

```
 setup: function (editor) {    
    editor.ui.registry.addButton('customInsertButton', {
      text: 'My Button',
      onAction: function (_) {
        editor.insertContent('&nbsp;<strong>It\'s my button!</strong>&nbsp;');
      }
    });
 }
```

In addition you should configure toolbar with added button:

```
 toolbar: 'customInsertButton'
```

Also you can access to `editor`s body content and change styles with the following function:

```
 editor.getBody().style
```

Based on this description, you can add 2 buttons to the toolbar for changing fontsize which one of them is increasing  `fontsize` and another for decreasing `fontsize`:

```
 setup: (editor) => {
            editor.ui.registry.addButton("btnIncreaseFontSize", {
              text: "A",
              icon: "action-prev",
              onAction: (api) => {
                let fontSize = editor.getBody().style.fontSize;
                if (!fontSize) fontSize = defaultFontSize;
                let value = parseInt(fontSize.substring(0, 2));
                fontSize = `${value + 1}px`;
                editor.getBody().style.fontSize = fontSize;
              }
            });
            editor.ui.registry.addButton("btnDecreaseFontSize", {
              text: "A",
              icon: "action-next",
              onAction: (api) => {
                let fontSize = editor.getBody().style.fontSize;
                if (!fontSize) fontSize = defaultFontSize;
                let value = parseInt(fontSize.substring(0, 2));
                fontSize = `${value - 1}px`;
                editor.getBody().style.fontSize = fontSize;
              }
            });
          }
```

**Note: for icon property had been used from `TinyMCE`s default [icon](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/editor-icon-identifiers/) pack**

Continually configure the toolbar like:

```
   toolbar:
            "undo redo | formatselect | " +
            "bold italic backcolor | alignleft aligncenter " +
            "alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | " +
            "removeformat | help | btnIncreaseFontSize | btnDecreaseFontSize",
          content_style: `body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:${defaultFontSize} }`,
```

And here's the `defaultFontSize`:

```
const defaultFontSize = "12px";
```

At the end here's the full code:

```
export default function App() {
  const defaultFontSize = "12px";

  return (
    <>
      <Editor
        initialValue="<p>This is the initial content of the editor.</p>"
        init={{
          height: 500,
          menubar: false,
          plugins: [
            "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
            "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
            "insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount"
          ],
          toolbar:
            "undo redo | formatselect | " +
            "bold italic backcolor | alignleft aligncenter " +
            "alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | " +
            "removeformat | help | btnIncreaseFontSize | btnDecreaseFontSize",
          content_style: `body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:${defaultFontSize} }`,
          setup: (editor) => {
            editor.ui.registry.addButton("btnIncreaseFontSize", {
              text: "A",
              icon: "action-prev",
              onAction: (api) => {
                let fontSize = editor.getBody().style.fontSize;
                if (!fontSize) fontSize = defaultFontSize;
                let value = parseInt(fontSize.substring(0, 2));
                fontSize = `${value + 1}px`;
                editor.getBody().style.fontSize = fontSize;
              }
            });
            editor.ui.registry.addButton("btnDecreaseFontSize", {
              text: "A",
              icon: "action-next",
              onAction: (api) => {
                let fontSize = editor.getBody().style.fontSize;
                if (!fontSize) fontSize = defaultFontSize;
                let value = parseInt(fontSize.substring(0, 2));
                fontSize = `${value - 1}px`;
                editor.getBody().style.fontSize = fontSize;
              }
            });
          }
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit polished-http-kf4lc]

Answer (score -1):

From what I could see you *might* be able to change the selector to do this, but safest is to use the configuration as per:
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#fontsize_formats

example:
tinymce.init({
selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
toolbar: 'fontsizeselect',
fontsize_formats: '8pt 10pt 12pt 14pt 16pt 18pt 24pt 36pt 48pt'
});